# typescript: call public function

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I'm new in `typescript`. In my `node-express` app, I want to call public function. But `this` is always `undefined`, so when I call public function, it throw always error. My code is given below:

**app.ts**

```
 import * as express from 'express';
 import User from './user/ctrl';
 class App {
    public express: express.Application;
    constructor() {
       this.express = express();
       this.routes();
    }
    private routes():void {
       let router = express.Router();
       router.get('/', User.index);
       this.express.use('/', router);
    }
 }

export default new App().express;
```

**./user/ctrl.ts**

```
class User {
   public demo:string;
   constructor() {
      this.demo = "this is text";
   }

   public infox() {
       console.log("demoo test : ", this.demo);
   }

   public index(req:any, res:any) {
       console.log(this) // output: undefined
       this.infox(); // throw an error.
   }
}

const user = new User();
export default user;
```

Server run at port `3000`.

Any suggestion??

Comment: Read about `this` scope in JavaScript.

Comment: `User.index` is **not** a static function, so you cannot pass it like that. If it was a static function then you couldn't use `this` inside it. Make up your mind.

Comment: Is it worth it using TS on back-end? Just seems weird to me...

Comment: @Lazyexpert Why is that weird? And yeah, it worth it.

Comment: @NitzanTomer `User` inside app.ts does not refer to the class. It refers to the instance exported from ctrl.ts.

Comment: @Saravana True that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you passed a reference the `User.index` function, the `this` inside it will change based on how it is called. Or when strict mode is on `this` will be undefined.

Change `router.get('/', User.index);` to `router.get('/', (req, res) => User.index(req, res));`. Notice that `User.index` is wrapped inside an arrow function which captures the correct `this` when `User.index` is called.

See [red flags for `this` in TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#red-flags-for-this)